# 'apr-util-devel' not found in package names. Trying capabilities

Tags: opensuse

I am trying to install Ganglia on my server. What is the equivalent package in openSuse for apr-util-devel

Comment: Google can tell you.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=apr-util-devel+package+in+opensuse

The first link (for me) is this question - the fourth link mentions OpenSuSE and libapr-util1-devel, and all of them suggest going to RPMFind (rpmfind.net), which when I go there, has a bunch of libapr devel packages.

Like I said, Google can tell you.

Comment: You can ignore my question if you didn't want to answer

Comment: @John rpmfind is only so good and sometimes breaks things.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Ganglia) is a tutorial.

Since we don't like posting links and running on U&L, I'll copy the part relevant for you.

> Prerequisites
>
> RRD
>
> RRD is required in case we want to have gmetad ().
>
> Install RRD which is a pre-requisite for Ganglia. You should be able to do this
>   using Yast, search and install rrdtool and rrdtool-devel in case we
>   are doing a tarball installation of Ganglia
>
> Apache Portable Runtime (APR)
>
> Library APR is required, please use Yast
>   to install libapr1 and libapr1-devel
>
> Confuse
>
> libConfuse is a configuration file parser library and is
>   required by Ganglia Please install using Yast - libconfuse-devel
>
> Expat
>
> Expat is an XML 1.0 parser written in C Yast - libexpat-devel
>
> PCRE
>
> Perl-compatible regular expressions Yast - pcre-devel

Of course, you don't have to use YaST, you can use zypper. So:

`zypper in rrdtool rrdtool-devel libapr1 libapr1-devel libconfuse-devel libexpat-devel pcre-devel`

should take care of you.

However, we have a `network:cluster` repo so you could also do:

```
zypper ar -refresh http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/cluster/openSUSE_VERSION/network:cluster.repo

zypper in  ganglia-web
```